# How can I populate an Array with records via a query using DateTime column and variable months, years

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on making a webshop and give administrators the ability to view data in a chart using ChartJs, ASP.NET Core Razor Pages for the view.
To show the data via the chart I use jQuery to change data from the chart without having to refresh the page therefore i need to have the data already loaded when the user is on the page.

Right now I am stuck on the part where I get my list of keys into an array. I get all of the data out of my "Key" table with a DateTime column formatted as "19-12-2018 18:46:34" (day-month-year-hours-minutes-seconds) and 8 other columns nothing related to DateTime

What i want to get: For the years 2016 until 2019 the days of each month
Below is a code example that works for specified year and month

I am using Razor pages with MVVM-pattern
This is from my code-behind page where I load the data I will use in the view of this page for Chart.js.

```
public List<Key>[] AllOrdersDays { get; set; }
AllOrdersDays = new List<Key>[31];

for (int day = 0; day < 32; day++)
{
AllOrdersDays[day] = (from key in _context.Key
                      where key.OrderDate.Year == 2018 && key.OrderDate.Month == 12 &&  key.OrderDate.Day == day
                      select key).ToList();
}
```

This works fine but i don't want to write this over and over for every month  for the years from 2016 until 2019

```
public List<Key>[] AllOrdersDays { get; set; }
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    AllOrdersDays = new List<Key>[10000];
    for (int year = 2016; year < 2019; year++)
    {
         for (int month = 1; month < 12; month++)
         {
             for (int day = 0; day < 32; day++)
             {
                 AllOrdersDays[day] = (from key in _context.Key
                                       where key.OrderDate.Year == year && key.OrderDate.Month == month && key.OrderDate.Day == day+1
                                       select key).ToList();
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

This is just a snippet from my page i left out all the irrelevant information.
OnGetAsync() is called when the user navigates to the page.
new List[10000] the 10000 is just a value because it had to be filled into the array to initiate.

The result I get is that the first 31 records will get the correct value but after it throws a NullReferenceException which i understand because "day" in the nested for-loop will never go above 31 so the array can only fill in the data for 1 month.

What i would like to know is a way to make this work.
This is not the most elegant solution probably but i don't want to hardcode my problems away.

Comment: You do not have to initiate a list with `[10000]`. Just doing a `new List<Key>()` does the trick as well. And day will also not go above 28 or 29 during February.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing that, which won't work correctly as not every month has the same amount of days (which could be easily worked-around, though), you could just get the list by dates by grouping on the date of the order.

```
var data = _context.Key
    .Where(key => key.OrderDate.Year > 2015)
    .GroupBy(key => key.OrderDate)
    .SelectMany(grp => new OrdersByDate 
    {
        // the date of the orders
        Date = grp.Key,
        // the list of orders for the date
        Orders = grp.ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

That would give you all orders by date. If you need to have Year, Month and Day separated, you could do so in the `OrdersByDate` class, which I created as a sample:

```
public class OrdersByDate
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Key> Orders { get; set; }
}
```